How to define sub-year groupings in ISO-8601 for climatology - What week numbers constitute a season?
ISO 8601 is a time/date standard that allows for sub-year groupings - for example, 2024-25 indicates a time period of Spring in the Northern Hemisphere, year 2024.
I am constructing a climatological normal using ISO 8601 groupings. Computing weekly data from daily data is trivial in this standard; however, deriving the appropriate groupings of weeks to comprise subyear periods appears to be less standardized.  It seems for months, the status quo is to divide the year into repeating intervals of months of 4 weeks, 4 weeks, and then 5 weeks, so 4-4-5-4-4-5-4-4-5-4-4-5, for a 52-week year.
My question is about the status quo for defining the start and end of seasons. Does Winter begin at week number 1 and end at week number 13? or does it span week numbers 50 -- 11?
Any guidance would be appreciated.
